# about jquery plugin define.when it will run?

Tags: jquery

I recently learning jquery plugin.but i have some confusion.like :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://libs.baidu.com/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function ($){
    $.fn.xxx=function(){
      console.log("define xxx");
    }
  })(jQuery)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

why the console doesn't print anything?

Answer (score 1):

You're defining a function, but you don't call it.

If you want to see something, call the function :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function ($){
    $.fn.xxx=function(){
      console.log("define xxx");
    }
  })(jQuery)
  jQuery(function(){
      jQuery(document).xxx();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: when the function is defining,the console.log() shouldn't be running?

Comment: Defining a function doesn't call it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function aswell right now you are only defining it

```
$().xxx()
```